# Validate DocBook document using XML Schema, DTD, RelaxNG and Schematron

Tags: java, xml, validation, relaxng

in my Java application I have to validate XML documents in different versions of DocBook format. DocBook 4 is based on DTD, DocBook 5 is based on RelaxNG/Schematron. What is the appropriate way for beeing able to validate against the different schema languages? I found Oracle Multi-Schema XML Validator (MSV), JARV and oNVDL. The latter seems to be deprecated. At the moment I use SAXParser/XMLReader. But there's no support for RelaxNG. I thought about combining with Jing but I look for a clean structure to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I work with a RELAX NG compact schema with embedded Schematron rules, but at least several of the popular RELAX NG validators (Jing, RNV) ignore this Schematron code. Currently our workflow is:

1. Convert the compact schema to the XML syntax with Trang
2. Extract the Schematron rules with Saxon and the XSLT stylesheet "RNG2Schtrn.xsl"
3. Use Jing to validate against the extracted ".sch" Schematron schema
4. Use Jing to validate against the original RELAX NG compact schema

Apparently Trang can convert XML 1.0 DTDs to RELAX NG, so you should be able to use Jing for all the three types of validation.

See https://github.com/citation-style-language/utilities/blob/master/style-qc.sh for our conversion script, and https://raw.github.com/citation-style-language/schema/master/csl.rnc to see our schema (Schematron rules near the top).